# Installing MS CRM IFD does not update registry and database

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

When I am trying to install the IFD tool on an on-premise CRM installation it is not updating the registry and the database.

Should the user doing the installation have some special permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Run the IFD tool as Administrator. It will work then.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to check the deployment guide, but I'd assume you'd want to be a Deployment Administrator.

I assume you mean "When I am trying to **run** the IFD tool" and not "install".

Comment: Yes thats right I am trying to run the IFD tool. The user i am running it under is a system administrator of the CRM. But I think the problem is not even with CRM its with trying to do the registry updates and the DB updates. I checked and the user was a sys admin for both the local system as well as the database.

Comment: I'm not sure how this gets locked down, but are you on Windows Server 2008?  Try right clicking and running the tool as Admin?

Comment: Also have you checked the logs at all?  It doesn't sound like they'll necessarily be overly helpful, but you never know.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948779 shows where the logs are.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the user you are logged into the server as is user who is a deployment administrator.  The User running the IFD tool must have rights to the MSCRM_CONFIG database.